# How can I track in Google Analytics a long list of all the A/B tests a user is assigned?

Tags: google-analytics, a-b-testing

For our site's A/B testing requirement we need to track all the tests a visitor is experiencing. This is set to grow to around 100 potentially running concurrently in the future.

We would like to track this in Google Analytics for subsequent analysis. However the maximum size of a custom dimension is 155 characters. Does anyone have a suggested workaround of how to track these kinds of long lists?